# What is the correct method to save a photo to my local drive

Tags: cakephp

This application is pretty straight forward. I have a video tag and a 2nd tag that captures that image when submit is pressed. What I am trying to do is save that image to the local drive, any drive just to get it working I can change it later. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

```
        <div class="cell">
        <video id="player" name="player" autoplay></video>
        </div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
          <canvas id="canvas" name="canvas" width="320px" height="240px"></canvas>
        </div>

    if ($this->request->is(['post','put',])) {
        $img = $_POST['canvas'];
        $folderPath = "Music/";

        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
        $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        $fileName = uniqid() . '.png';

        $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
        file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

        print_r($fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Which part of your code isn't doing what you expect? What's it doing instead?

Comment: So I got the upload location to work correctly but now the png files that are being uploaded are blank or have no picture. How exactly do i pass a image into my php code?

Comment: When you `base64_decode` the data, do you get anything back, or an error of some sort? My first guess would be that the `png` file is blank because you're writing zero bytes to them.